# jQuery--result length

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm using asp.net and Jquery Cascading Dropdown. I'm getting Values but not getting bind. The result of `JSON` is giving length as total chars not total Records

The Result is

```
{
"Table": [
    {
        "VoyageMasterID": 3,
        "VoyageCode": "9101"
    },
    {
        "VoyageMasterID": 7,
        "VoyageCode": "1617"
    }
]
}
```

But its giving length as 93

But here my total records are just 2

Hence when i bind values to Dropdown its not getting bind.

My Json :

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Port.aspx/Code_Get",
                    data: "{ServiceID:'" + $(".ddlService").val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        try {      
                            Success(data.d);
                            // 

  function Success(result) {         
        $(".ddlVoyage").empty();
        $(".ddlVoyage").append("<option  value=''>Select </option>");
        $.each(result, function (index, value) {              
        $(".ddlVoyage").append("<option value='" + value.VoyageMasterID + "'>" + value.VoyageCode + "</option>");
        });
    }
```

Iam not getting Data Bind to Select , as my Data from Json is Not giving proper result.

can any one please help

Comment: is this complete code?

Comment: No No just wanted to know the main part of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `data` is coming back as a string from your service, rather than an actual JSON object.

Try this for the array length:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data.d);
console.log(json.length);
```

Comment: Ohh Parsing, Forgot about that

Comment: Yes by Parsing and using Table[0] as it is string its working